# Java try with resources with Reader and Writer on the same file

Tags: java, io, java-io

```
try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
     Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
    ...
} catch (IOException exception) {
    ...
}
```

Can I use Reader and Writer which open the same file in try-with-resources? Is it safe?

Comment: Depends totally on what you expect to happen.  Opening a file for writing truncates the file.  Did you try the code to see if it does what you want?

Comment: In a word:  no.  Windows probably won’t even allow it;  other systems will let you try it, but as Jim said, you won’t read any data.  Write to a [temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)), then when you’re done, [move](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) that file on top of the original one.

Comment: @VGR it’s even possible under Windows. You can also circumvent the truncation by specifying your own open options. In limited use cases, it might even do the right thing, though I still wouldn’t recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's allowed, it's just waiting for problems to occur. `Reader` and `Writer` are not meant to work on the same file.

There are alternatives that you can look into. Good old [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) is created to support both reading and writing. It's not great for text though. [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), accessible from a `RandomAccessFile` or using `FileChannel.open` is newer but still doesn't work well with text.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bad practice. Different operating system will give you inconsistent results and it's asking for problems.

You'd be better off reading the file, writing to a temporary file, then replacing the old file with the temporary file when you're done.